# Orgmode automatically increment an unordered list

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, list

I use org-mode for planning projects and tasks, etc. Say I am reading a book and I want to track my progress chapter by chapter. I want to create a list of repetitive elements with an incremented number like:

```
- [ ] chapter 1
- [ ] chapter 2
- [ ] chapter 3
...
```

Now, instead of typing out the incremented numbers each time, is there a way to just type the first entry, like `- [ ] chapter 1` and then have org-mode complete `n` additional entries. So if a book has 10 chapters, then orgmode would increment the entry 10 times?

So I was just wondering if there is a way to do this in orgmode or a different package to use, etc? Note that I use Spacemacs.

Comment: Not that I know of: the text in a list item is arbitrary and I don't think that org mode makes any special effort to decipher it (e.g. the way that it does with table entries in `org-table-copy-down`). But it's easy enough to write a function that does that and it doesn't have to know anything about org: just insert the text in a  counted loop.

Answer (score 4):

This simple function will do that:

```el
(defun insert-chapters-todo (count)
  (interactive "nChapters count: ")
  (dolist (n (number-sequence 1 count))
    (insert (format "- [ ] chapter %d\n" n))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the traditional way would be to use macros. I'm not a
Spacemacs user, but I used to use Vim years ago and remember it has a
way of incrementing the number at point (maybe it was `C-a` to
increment and `C-x` to decrement, but I'm not sure). I'm sure
Spacemacs either has the same functionality or there is an existing
package that adds it. I would do something like this in Vim:

- Type the first line `- [ ] Chapter 1`.
- Record a macro that yanks and pastes the line and then increments
  the number: `qayyp$<C-a>q` (The `<C-a>` means control-a, I think
  that's the syntax Vim uses for keys, I don't if Spacemacs uses it or
  prefers Emacs syntax).
- Run it as many times as you like.

In Emacs keyboard macros have a counter so this is easy. In vanilla
Emacs keybindings you can use `C-1 <f3> - [ ] Chapter <f3> <ret> C-5
<f4>` to get five chapters. (The `C-1` is to start the counter at one,
it usually starts at 0.)